# Hide name of nested object field in GSON serialization

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

My question is similar to the one found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37546117/gson-remove-unnecessary-nested-object-fields) but I am not looking to hide fields of a nested object. I just want to hide the name of a nested object in a wrapper class.

My class structure is something like

```
public class Outer {
    Inner obj;
}

public class Inner {
    String a;
    String b;
}
```

When serializing an instance of `Outer` I would like it to appear the same as a serialization of `Inner`. Like:

```
{
   "a":"abc",
   "b":"xyz"
}
```

and not

```
{
    "obj" : {
        "a":"abc",
        "b":"xyz"
    }
}
```

Is there an annotation I can use, or do I need to implement my own TypeAdapter similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34123721/gson-de-serialization-of-wrapper-class)?

Comment: You need your own TypeAdapter.

Comment: @Aposhian 
and if you want the object to look like you add something else
public class Outer {
    Inner obj;
    something other;
}